# iOS - Find Max Width for Label With >= Constraint to Another Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

Say I have a label constrained to the left side of the container and a button constrained to the right side with a fixed width. If I set the horizontal spacing between the label and the button to be something like >= 8, is there any way to get the max width to which the label could stretch before the content starts being compressed to accommodate for the >= constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just read documentation about this methods of UIView

```
- (void)setContentCompressionResistancePriority:(UILayoutPriority)priority forAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis
- (void)setContentHuggingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)priority forAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just got around to checking these out and I don't see anything in the documentation for those methods about being able to find the max content size of the object based on constraints -- only how to set the resistance to the view size being larger/smaller than the intrinsic size.

Comment: Ok.pls write your example code with rules of constraints, i try help you.